# WooCommerce multiple redirections after a purchase

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect, woocommerce, orders

The following code below, redirects the customer to a custom page after a purchase in WooCommerce. In this custom page user can buy additional item (modifying order with adding new item):

code edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following instead to avoid your redirection issue on order received:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_created', 'set_wc_session_original_order_id');
function set_wc_session_original_order_id( $order ) {
    WC()->session->set('original_order_id', $order->get_id());
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'custom_shop_order_process_redirects');
function custom_shop_order_process_redirects() {
    if ( is_page('upsell-1') && isset($_GET['woocommerce_checkout_place_order'])) {
        $order_id = WC()->session->get('original_order_id');
        if ( $order_id > 0 ) {
            $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
            $order->add_product(wc_get_product('875'));
            $order->calculate_totals(); // Already includes save() method

            WC()->session->__unset('original_order_id'); // Remove session variable

            wp_redirect( $order->get_checkout_order_received_url() );
            exit;
        } 
    } elseif ( is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') && WC()->session->__isset('original_order_id') ) {
        wp_redirect( home_url('/upsell-1') );
        exit;
    }
}
```

It should work.

Comment: Okay this works, but I want that if additional item was purchased from upsell page then user would not be able to access upsell page again. Do I need to use meta data on order for it to work?

Comment: @razor60 What you can do is to set 2 different WC Session variables, so `'original_order_id'` and `'order_received_redirect'` *(with `'1'` as value)*… Then you keep `'original_order_id'` for the order ID and you use `'order_received_redirect'` for the redirection logic with `__isset()` and `__unset()`…

Comment: LoicTheAztec, I will create a new separate thread with more detailed explanation